# In ADF use a lookup output as a parameter for an Oracle Query

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm a complete beginner with Azure Data Factory and I'm struggling to set a parameter using a lookup output, and then use the parameter within my query to import data.

I'm using an Azure SQL database as the source for the lookup and an Oracle database as the source for the copy data

My lookup query works ok and my copy data query works without a parameter so I know I'm part way there, but I'm struggling with the parameter part.

My lookup details are below with the output query
[image]
[image]

The copy data query is below with the lookup activity as the parameter added but as you can see it's not correct.
[image]

I'm not sure if I should be using the lookup as the parameter or if I should be using a parameter with the value generated from the lookup. In which case I have no idea how to do this.
I'm also pretty sure the parameter in the query needs some work as even hardcoding a parameter doesn't seem to work.

If anyone can help to get this working I'd be very grateful.
There doesn't seem to be much help with turning lookups into parameters on the internet.

Thanks in advance for any help anyone can give.

Comment: Try enclosing the lookup output as follows. Select column from table where rowstamp> '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstrow.RowStamp}'

Comment: @AllAboutBI that worked perfectly thank you. I knew it would be something simple like that. I just wish there was more information on the internet for ADF like there is for SQL language.

Comment: Thanks, Alix. I have posted it as answer. Please accept it as answer..

Answer (score 0):

Try enclosing the lookup output as follows. Select column from table where rowstamp> '@{activity('Lookup1').output.firstrow.RowStamp}'